# Gedit is having problems starting up

Tags: gedit

I just installed the new version of Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit). Mr processor is intel i7. I am noticing that Gedit is having problems starting up. I start it then it crashes out with no error message and I have to click the icon again to start it. I am having the same problem with the built in file manager. I will click on some folder and the window for the application will close entirely. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this an upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried launching gedit from the terminal to see if its giving any error codes or issues?

Answer (score 2):

If this is an upgrade, you might be bringing forward old configuration that could be messing things up. I suggest you run the following to reset the configuration:

```
mv ~/.gconf/apps/gedit-2{,-OLD}
mv ~/.config/gedit{,-OLD}
mv ~/.gnome2/gedit{,-OLD}
```

After you've done that, gedit *should* start with a fresh configuration if it doesn't you might want to run `find ~ -name '*gedit*'` and see if there are any other places that config is hiding out.

---

If that doesn't help, you want to file a bug!

```
ubuntu-bug gedit
```

Comment: I installed Ocelot again this time checking the box "download updates while installing". All my problems seemed to vanish and what I am left with is a kick a** OS.