# Shift + any key combination closes search dialog in gedit on 14.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

When I hit Ctrl+F and type any uppercase letter (using the Shift key) in the search dialog, the dialog closes and the letters appears in the document instead. I don't remember changing any shortcut configuration. What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting or logging back in? It might be a temp glitch.

Comment: silly questions, but does this happen as well if you choose "search" from the menu? and another question: does it happen as well if you search with Control_R+F?

Comment: Two more: did you ever use xdotools to set up key combinations, or made special key combinations in System preferences > Keyboard > shortcuts? (although you alredy mentioned you didn't)

Comment: Try [@Oli's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/67840/283843) to reset gedit configuration

Comment: @JacobVlijm in Keyboard shorcuts, I added Shift+Shift R in Typing as "Switch to next source". That was indeed the cause. Do you have any idea why this shortcut causes the behavior I described? I have been using this combination since Ubuntu 08.10 or so.

Comment: Actually I was hoping to find a key combination that would somehow cause <Esc>, which "officially" causes the search box to close, but I guess this is one of those weird coincidences that internally causes unpredicted behaviour.

Comment: @JacobVlijm care to sum your comments as an answer so that I can award you the bounty?

Comment: @JacobVlijm weird, if I click on the bounty icon and confirm the dialog, it still doesn't get awarded... that looks like a bug on SE itself :)

Comment: Don't worry, glad it worked anyway, I'll see what happens :) I think it is the grace period that needs manual awarding.

Comment: @prasopes, thank you for finding the Shift+Shift R problem! I was having this issue for quite awhile and never found any info about it until now.  Have you reported it in launchpad?

Comment: Found the bug report, once I knew what to look for: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1440876 Please report there if this bug affects you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gedit, there are several ways to close the search box. According to [this site](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-search.html.en), it closes when you press either <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (of course it is probably in the help file as well). The search is to find any shortcuts you might have set in the past that could work as one of those keys.

What I would try to find directions:

- does this happen as well if you choose "search" from the menu?
- does it happen as well if you search with Control_R+F?
- did you ever use xdotools to set up key combinations, or made special key combinations in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts?

Try and see if any of these can give you a clue, look into System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts, disable all and see if the problem is fixed. Activate them one by one to see which one gives the error.